# Como recuperar o commit anterior?

Tags: git

Depois de ter adicionado arquivo modificado e ter dado *commit*, precisei modificar toda a estrutura do código, mas não funcionou e queria ter acesso ao código anterior novamente.

Como recupero o conteúdo do *commit* anterior?

Comment: Recomendo botar no ``.gitconfig`` o seguinte: ``undo = reset HEAD~1 --mixed``

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

Isso retornará para o último commit, mas deixando as modificações no arquivo em estado `unstaged`. Caso você queira apagar as alterações, o comando é:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Comment: Mas é possível ver o código que digitei antes do commit?

Comment: Como eu disse, sem o `--hard` ele vai manter as alterações no arquivo, só que `unstaged`, caso você utilizar a opção, daí ele volta pro estado do arquivo que estava no commit.

Answer (score 6):

Para desfazer o ultimo commit podes fazer:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Desse modo vais perder o commit mas manter todo o código que tinhas "commitado" e o estado atual, antes de fazer o reset.

Se quiseres vêr o que foi feito no ultimo(s) commit podes fazer:

```
$ git log -p -2
```

Assim vês o hash e as mudanças dos ultimos dois commits.

Podes também saltar para um novo ramo `$ git checkout -b novo-ramo` e fazer o checkout desse commit especifico:

```
$ git checkout 12345678901234567890123456789012345678ab
```

Answer (score 4):

Os passos que costumo dar para um colocar o código em determinado estado de desenvolvimento são:

1. Listar os *commits* efetuados:

   ```
   git log
   ```
2. Identificar qual o *commit* que me interessa repor através da sua *hash*, por exemplo:

   ```
   Commit: 54eb79a5590d1716b9ac335457230d771181f4a7

   Author: Lahan

   Date:   Tue Dec 23 23:36:01 2014 +0100

   Message: Added 'mobile' field to user table in profiler app
   ```
3. Efetuar um *reset*, assinalando a *hash* do *commit* que pretendo seja o novo estado do código:

   ```
   git reset --hard 54eb79a
   ```

Agora todo o código encontra-se no estado em que ficou após ser feito o *commit* com a *hash* `54eb79a5590d1716b9ac335457230d771181f4a7`

Comment: Isto apagará o commit. Creio que não seja esta a pergunta do AP.